# where ethereum application store data

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, truffle, private-blockchain, voting

I run one simple voting application in ethereum....

i want to know where they store the data(no of votes)..

what is the mechanism for storing data..

or where data persist in ethereum

i am referring

https://medium.com/@mvmurthy/full-stack-hello-world-voting-ethereum-dapp-tutorial-part-1-40d2d0d807c2

can anyone explain..?

Answer (score 3):

The dApp uses a smart contract to handle the voting. Therefore the data resides within the Ethereum blockchain and inside the smart contract. Physically the data is "replicated" across the entire network to all its nodes (thousands).

You should check the Ethereum White Paper https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/White-Paper (and possibly also Yellow Paper) for more details on how the Ethereum network works.